# SQL - Select all rows added yesterday efficiently

Tags: sql, select, date, performance

I want to select all of the rows added to a table which were added "yesterday" i.e. the day before whenever I choose to run the query.

At the moment my query looks like this:

```
SELECT row_date (etc)
WHERE  row_date >= trunc(sysdate-1)
       and row_date < truc(sysdate);
```

Is there a more efficient (and, hopefully, readable) way of achieving this?

Cheers,

Pete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That query doesn't look like it can be optimised to me. You've made it [sargable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799584/what-makes-a-sql-statement-sargable) by avoiding wrapping the column itself in any date/time functions.

Do you have an index on row_date?

Comment: I don't have an index on row_date at the moment.

Comment: @Peter - What RDBMS are you using?